# As you can see my json object i want to put my json object in a text file and let my js code read my json object from a text file

Tags: javascript, html, json

As you can see my json object i want to put my json object in a text file and let my js code read my json object from a text file but i dont know how to do it pls help

```
var objs = [{
  "Object": {
    "ID": 1,
    "type": "button",
    "color": "red",
    "Text": "I Love",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  },
  "Object ": {
    "ID": 2,
    "type": "button",
    "color": "red",
    "Text": "I Love",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "Font": {
      "fontName": "tahoma",
      "font": "150px"
    }
  }
}]
objs.forEach(function(Object) {
  var Elm = document.createElement('text');
  Elm.textContent = Element.Object + ' ' + Element.code.hex;
  Elm.style.backgroundColor = Element.code.hex;
  document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(Elm);
});
```

Comment: There's no code here, just a single literal assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you need fix the JSON so its an array of objects not an array of one object which has the same key for Object.

Then remove the space in `Object` , and then in change Object to something else, like item `forEach(function(item) {` then its not `Element` but `item`.

I have no idea what `Element.code.hex` is so removed it.

```js
var objs = [{
    "Object": {
      "ID": 1,
      "type": "button",
      "color": "red",
      "Text": "I Love",
      "width": "100px",
      "height": "100px",
      "Font": {
        "fontName": "tahoma",
        "font": "150px"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Object": {
      "ID": 2,
      "type": "button",
      "color": "green",
      "Text": "I Hate",
      "width": "100px",
      "height": "100px",
      "Font": {
        "fontName": "tahoma",
        "font": "150px"
      }
    }
  }
]

objs.forEach(function(item) {
  var Elm = document.createElement(item.Object.type);
  Elm.textContent = item.Object.Text;
  Elm.style.backgroundColor = item.Object.color;

  // apply other props
  //...

  document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(Elm);
});
```

```html
<div id="ColorArea"></div>
```

Note, having it be `item.Object` is not needed, you could simply use an array which contains the objects, no need to nest it further inside Object